Create a box for only the last 5 bars: A Simple Problem I can't crack
I want to create a box around the last 5 bars. I only want to draw one box on the chart.
I have written this code, but it doesnt work.
// @version=5
indicator("One Box", overlay=true)

var int left = na
if barstate.islast
    left := bar_index-5

top    = ta.highest(5)
bottom = ta.lowest(5)
box.new(left= left ,top= top, right= bar_index, bottom= bottom)

Many thanks

What's the issue right now? Is it you having more than one box?

Yes, it is. my code draws lots of boxes. I want to create only one box around the last 5 bars.

After you reate your box, you need to delete the previous instance. No need for any if check.
top    = ta.highest(5)
bottom = ta.lowest(5)

bx = box.new(left=bar_index - 4, top=top, right=bar_index, bottom=bottom)
box.delete(bx[1])

Or declare your box with the var keyword and just move it on every bar. This will be more performance efficient.
top    = ta.highest(5)
bottom = ta.lowest(5)

var bx = box.new(na, na, na, na)

box.set_lefttop(bx, bar_index - 4, top)
box.set_rightbottom(bx, bar_index, bottom)


Thank you very much for your codes. They work perfectly. :)

I edited my code and this is the answer: I changed the position of the if block
// @version=5
indicator("One Box", overlay=true)


left = bar_index[4]
top    = ta.highest(5)
bottom = ta.lowest(5)

if barstate.islast
    box.new(left= left ,top= top, right= bar_index, bottom= bottom)


This is actually not the answer you are looking for. This will still create a new box when a new bar forms. Run it on a small timeframe like 5 seconds or so and you will see. See my answer for the correct way of doing this.

As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
